# C# Get double click listbox selected

Tags: c#, events

I'm having trouble with some C#..
I have a listbox, when I double click an entry I want to return the string of whatever I double clicked..

How do I do this?

Comment: On the double click handler check **SelectedItem** property. Double clicked item is selected too.

Comment: Sorry, what is the double click handler? I have no idea how to register events except double clicking on things like buttons to go from the GUI to the code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx
You need to read up on how to connect events in WinForms though, that's probably too big of a question to post on stackoverflow, just search google for tutorials.

Comment: You will need to go to the properties window of your control, select the lightning bolt to go to events and then you can either double click the event you want to add or add an existing eventhandler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using WinForms.

If you're working with single selection then it's pretty easy: on the double click handler (please check how to do it with Google or see later) check `SelectedItem` property. Double clicked item is selected too.

```
void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var list = (ListBox)sender;

    // This is your selected item
    object item = list.SelectedItem;
}
```

If you're working with multi-selection you need to be more check which item has been clicked because it may be last selected one, you can use `IndexFromPoint()` method like this:

```
void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var list = (ListBox)sender;

    int itemIndex = list.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (itemIndex != -1)
    {
        // This is your double clicked item
        object item = list.Items[itemIndex];
    }
}
```

**EDIT** How to add an event handler? Google is your friend here but in short you have to select the control, open properties page, select events then double click the input box near `MouseDoubleClick` event. Designer will add code for you anyway you should first start with that basics...